# How to draw polyline across Pacific ocean (-180/180 point) using WPF bing maps control?

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

Polyline with following locations:

```
var locations = new LocationCollection() 
            { 
                new Location(0, 160), 
                new Location(5, 170), 
                new Location(9.5, 179.999),
                new Location(10.5, -179.999),
                new Location(15, -170),
                new Location(20, -160)
            };
```

Causes control to to draw line across whole globe instead of just pacific (because of wrapping globes i guess) but is there workaround over that?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given on MSDN forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fae1b3f-67a4-49ab-8fc8-1287316ef54f/how-can-one-draw-a-polyline-across-pacific-ocean#9a60a298-08cd-4f66-ba73-16865b4ac1eb